# Scorm weekly interactions report in Moodle

Tags: moodle, scorm, moodle-api

I am entirely new to Moodle and have been asked to export the interactions of around 50 quizzes weekly.
For the first week I did it manually but it's a real pain...
I am looking for a way to trigger something to produce and send or save every interactions report on Monday, for example.

I've googled and looked for a solution in the moodle Docs but either I am not looking in the right place, either I am the only one in the world trying to do something of the sort, which I strongly doubt.

I have accees to the database and have got administrator privileges

Any help would be most welcome,

Thank you.

Comment: What are you doing with the data?

Comment: Sending it to my client. I don't actually know what he does with it